# Why does calling matrix block type before matrix block loop lead to no loop output

Tags: matrix

In the code below I am trying to check for the presence of a quote block to help define some layout columns.

As soon as i count an individual block, the loop block below it outputs nothing. If remove the column logic based on length of quote block the loop below then outputs.

```
{# position columns width if there is a quote #}
{% if entry.contentBlock.type('quote').limit(1) | length %}
    {% set col1 = "12u$(medium) 7u  " %}
    {% set col2 = "5u 12u$(medium)  " %}
{% else %}
    {% set col1 = "12u$(small) 6u -3u  " %}
    {% set col2 = "hide " %}
{% endif %}

<div class="{{ col1 }}">
    <h3> {{ entry.title }} </h3>

    {% for block in entry.contentBlock.all() %}
        {% if block.type.handle == "text" or block.type.handle == "image" %}
            {% include ('page/_partials/_' ~ blockPrefix ~ 'block_' ~ block.type.handle) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="{{ col2 }}">
    {% for block in entry.contentBlock.type('quote').all() %}
        {% include ('page/_partials/_' ~ blockPrefix ~ 'block_' ~ block.type.handle) %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is for Craft 3?

Comment: Yes this is for craft 3